# Assign an image to a picturebox from another form

Tags: vb.net, picturebox

I have a program with 16 blank picturebox's on the main form (`MainForm`).

When a user clicks a box a second form (`form2`) is opened which has 17 pictureboxes, each with a specific image. I want the specific image to go into the picturebox that was clicked on the main form.

I used this code on `form2` when one of the 17 pictureboxes is clicked

```
With Mainform.picturebox1
    .image = My.Resources._apicture01
     End With
```

However, when I click on `picturebox2` on the main form the picture chosen in `form2` is assigned to `Mainform.picturebox1` rather than `picturebox2`.

I need a way of having the code figure out which of the 16 pictureboxes on the main form was clicked, then have it add the chosen image to that picturebox.

Comment: Have you considered creating a class-level field (variable) in `MainForm` of the data type `PictureBox` and assigning the Picturebox that's clicked to it? Call it, for example, `Dim boxClicked as PictureBox`. Then you should be able to use something like `boxClicked.image = MyResouces._apicture01`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there a two ways.  The first assumes that your form2 is used to select the photo only and then closes, returning to the Main form.

In this case, add a public image property to form2 like this:

```
Private _selectedImage As Image
Public ReadOnly Property SelectedImage As Image
    Get
        Return _selectedImage
    End Get
End Property
```

then in form2, when selecting the image, set _selectedImage to the image and close the form with:

```
Me.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK
```

Back in Main form, set an event handler for Click event of all picture boxes like:

```
AddHandler PictureBox1.Click, AddressOf PictureBox_Click
AddHandler PictureBox2.Click, AddressOf PictureBox_Click
```

and so on.  The click event handler should be something like this:

```
    Private Sub PictureBox_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) 
      Dim PB As PictureBox = DirectCast(sender, PictureBox)
      Using F As New Form2()
        If F.ShowDialog = DialogResult.OK Then
            PB.Image = F.SelectedImage
        End If
      End Using
    End Sub
```

The other way would be to pass the picturebox to Form2 either as a property or as a parameter and then setting image to that picturebox in Form2, but I prefer option 1.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I would tackle the problem:

- Create a property on Form2 that stores the image that was clicked
- In your PictureBox click events on Form2, set the property to the respective PictureBox's image, set the Form's DialogResult to OK, and then close the form.
- In your PictureBox click events on Form1, call ShowDialog on the form, check if the DialogResult is OK, and if so then set the respective PictureBox's image to the property declared in the first step

In your Form2, you would add all of your PictureBox controls and set their images in the designer. Your code for Form2 would look like this:

```
Public Class Form2
  Public Property SelectedImage As Image

  Private Sub Form2_PictureBoxClicked(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles PictureBox1.Click, PictureBox2.Click, PictureBox3.Click, PictureBox4.Click, PictureBox5.Click, PictureBox6.Click, PictureBox7.Click, PictureBox8.Click, PictureBox9.Click, PictureBox10.Click, PictureBox11.Click, PictureBox12.Click, PictureBox13.Click, PictureBox14.Click, PictureBox15.Click, PictureBox16.Click, PictureBox16.Click
    Dim clickedButton As Button = DirectCast(sender, PictureBox)
    With Me
      .SelectedImage = clickedButton.Image
      .DialogResult = DialogResult.Ok
      .Close()
    End With
  End Sub
End Class
```

Then in your Form1, you would add all of your PictureBox controls in the designer and the code for Form1 would look like this:

```
Public Class Form1
  Private Sub Form1_PictureBoxClicked(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles PictureBox1.Click, PictureBox2.Click, PictureBox3.Click, PictureBox4.Click, PictureBox5.Click, PictureBox6.Click, PictureBox7.Click, PictureBox8.Click, PictureBox9.Click, PictureBox10.Click, PictureBox11.Click, PictureBox12.Click, PictureBox13.Click, PictureBox14.Click, PictureBox15.Click, PictureBox16.Click
    Dim clickedButton As Button = DirectCast(sender, PictureBox)
    Using frm2 As Form2 = New Form2()
      If frm2.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.Ok Then
        clickedButton.Image = frm2.SelectedImage
      End If
    End Using
  End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Hi David thanks for the reply, I tried what you wrote but it gave an error "System.InvalidCastException: 'Unable to cast object of type 'System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox' to type 'System.Windows.Forms.Button'.'"  The problem is this part "Dim clickedButton As Button = DirectCast(sender, Button)"

Comment: @funkymunkey99 that was a typo (I freetyped the code) where it was trying to cast the sender to a button instead of a picturebox. I've updated the code in my post.